# How to downgrade python version without affecting other files

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

When I am installing tensorflow in python 3.8.0 then it shows error. How to downgrade python version without affecting other files.

```
(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>pip uninstall python 3.8.4
WARNING: Skipping python as it is not installed.
WARNING: Skipping 3.8.4 as it is not installed.

(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>pip uninstall python-3.8.4
WARNING: Skipping python-3.8.4 as it is not installed.


(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>make altinstall python-3.7
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>pip install python-3.7
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-3.7 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-3.7
```

When I type the command `pip show tensorflow` it gives me this

```
(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>python --version
Python 3.8.5

(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>pip show tensorflow
WARNING: Package(s) not found: tensorflow
```

When I am installing tensorflow by using this command:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

it gives this error

```
(base) C:\Users\Akanksha-Lab-PC>pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-2.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (370.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.15.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Collecting astunparse~=1.6.3
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions~=3.7.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel~=0.35 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.35.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy~=1.19.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.19.2)
Processing c:\users\akanksha-lab-pc\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a0\16\9c\5473df82468f958445479c59e784896fa24f4a5fc024b0f501\termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers~=1.12.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12)
Collecting absl-py~=0.10
  Using cached absl_py-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py~=2.10.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Collecting keras-preprocessing~=1.1.2
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta~=0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Collecting gast==0.3.3
  Using cached gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Collecting grpcio~=1.32.0
  Using cached grpcio-1.32.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (2.6 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.5.0,>=2.4.0
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
Collecting tensorboard~=2.4
  Using cached tensorboard-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (10.6 MB)
Collecting opt-einsum~=3.3.0
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Processing c:\users\akanksha-lab-pc\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\5f\fd\9e\b6cf5890494cb8ef0b5eaff72e5d55a70fb56316007d6dfe73\wrapt-1.12.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (50.3.1.post20201107)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached Markdown-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Using cached google_auth-1.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (781 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.6"
  Using cached rsa-4.7-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.4->tensorflow) (1.25.11)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Installing collected packages: astunparse, termcolor, absl-py, keras-preprocessing, gast, grpcio, tensorflow-estimator, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, cachetools, rsa, google-auth, google-auth-oauthlib, markdown, tensorboard-plugin-wit, tensorboard, opt-einsum, wrapt, tensorflow
  Attempting uninstall: wrapt
    Found existing installation: wrapt 1.11.2
    Uninstalling wrapt-1.11.2:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\wrapt-1.11.2.dist-info\\INSTALLER'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Can anybody tell me the solution of this?

Comment: TF is compatible with Python 3.8, what kind of error did you get?

Comment: see above code i updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip uninstall python 3.8.4
```

This command will never work. `pip` is a python package manager, i.e. for an installation of python, pip is responsible to install modules to that python installation. It does not manage the installation of python itself

---

To your error with the tensorflow installation:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\wrapt-1.11.2.dist-info\\INSTALLER'
```

This is caused by the fact that the `c:\\programdata` is write protected from non-admin users, so in order for your command to succeed, you should run your cmd as admin.

**BUT**:

It seems like you have installed anaconda and are trying to install `tensorflow` into the base environment using `pip`. Pip in turn tries to uninstall some already existing package, probably to fulfill the tensorflow requirements. But the already existing package are probably installed by `conda` when you first installed anaconda, so you ware getting into dangerous waters here and you are risking to break your base environment, so two suggestions:

1. Create a new environment `conda create -n tf tensorflow-gpu`
2. Use conda commands to install tensorflow. `conda install tensorflow-gpu` will give you tensorflow

---

To your other question:

> How to downgrade python

The solution is also to use a conda command:

```
conda install python=<some version>
```

or, even better, simply create an environment with the version you need:

```
conda create -n py37 python=3.7
```

would for example give you an environment called py37 with python3.7 installed. It can be activated and used with

```
conda activate py37
```

Comment: conda install python = 3.7 helped me to downgrade the version.